# how to access a control in a custom style from code behind in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

How can I access the "image" from code behind in order to change its image source?
xaml code looks like this

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="Demo.ChartButton"
d:DesignWidth="100" d:DesignHeight="100">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="White"  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="image" d:IsOptimized="True" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.ShadowDepth)" Storyboard.TargetName="image" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.BlurRadius)" Storyboard.TargetName="image" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="image" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="AntiqueWhite" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="image" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="image" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="image" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FFAFAFAF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="image" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>

                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Image x:Name="image" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0" Source="/Demo;component/spreadsheet-icon.png" >
                            <Image.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="10" Color="Black" Opacity="1"/>
                            </Image.Effect>
                        </Image>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Button Content="" Margin="0,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" Click="Button_Click" />
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to access this is to navigate the visual tree to locate the image. Using [Linq-To-VisualTree](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/), you can locate it as follows:

```
using LinqToVisualTree

private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Button button = sender as Button;
  Image img = button.Descendants<Image>().Single() as Image;
  img.Source = "..."
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I thought there may be a simplier way to do it and looking for that.

Comment: Unfortunately not. However, a better approach might be to create your own Button subclass that exposes the Image Source as a dependency property.